# How can I access the viewholder of an item in a recycler view?

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have got a recycler view that shows a list of images. I have added an onScrollListener to that recycler view.

Now, when a scroll is detected, I would like to set the translation of the imageviews in the viewholders. Therefore I need a reference to the underlying view holders.

How can I get those?

In code (this won't work, but you will get the idea what I want to achieve):

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) ((RecyclerFragmentAdapter.MyViewHolder) 
    mRecyclerView.getChildAt(i)).itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
// ... Modify imageview, i.e. imageView.setImageMatrix(customImageMatrix);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Would `ItemAnimator`s work? https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators

Answer (score 6):

```
RecyclerView.getChildViewHolder()
RecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition()
RecyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition()
```