# Changing TextView size inside CardView

Tags: android

I've created CardView inside RecyclerView.

My XML for CardView looks like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I've created the Adapter and successfully shown the data to CardView that inside RecyclerView.

But I failed when I added Button in my activity_main.xml to change size of textView.
My program looks like this:

```html
textView =findViewById(R.id.textView);
button = findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        textView.setTextSize(42);
    }
});
```

The error message is:

```
 2022-04-18 13:28:47.264 3144-3144/com.example.myapplication 
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 3144
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTextSize(float)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:39)
```

How to solve those problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Update text of recycleview item

1. get position of that item in Recycleview
2. I am assuming you have a list of items that you passed to adapter , get
   that item using position you get from step 1
   e.g  list.get(postion)
3. now update this item field that shows text on item
4. user adapter.notifyItemChanged(postion , updatedItem

### Pseudo Kotlin code-->

```
fun updateTextView(position:Int){

  val item = list[position]
  item.text = "new_text"
  adapter.notifyItemChanged(postion , item)

}
```

Comment: I add variable 'size' in my Model. I use this variable in my adapter, in function onBindViewHolder particularly. Hence, inside setOnClickListener, I used item.size = 42, and the call adapter.notifyItemChange. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access `TextView` directly in `RecyclerView` this way. You should get a `ViewHolder` via adapter and change it there.

```
val item = adapter.get(1) // Or another method to get an item from a collection
```

See [How can I access the viewholder of an item in a recycler view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31222647/how-can-i-access-the-viewholder-of-an-item-in-a-recycler-view) to access `ViewHolder` directly. Or change `TextView` in a listener bound in `onBindViewHolder`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't Initialize your textView in MainActivity

Do it in your adapter

Like below example :

<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

```
private Context mContext;
private List<ModelRecycler> mData;

public MyAdapter (Context mContext, List<ModelRecycler> mData) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mData = mData;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.textView.setTextSize(42);
   
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView textView;
   
    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        
    }
}
```

}